# vscode report undefined symbol which has been actually included

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

The source code is very simple.

```
#include <signal.h>

void main() {
    sigset_t set;
}
```

The signal.h has been included in which sigset_t should have been defined. But vscode still report a problem.

```
identifier "sigset_t" is undefined
```

The config file is as below.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And the program can be successfully compiled with no error. Why does vscode report that error?

Comment: "And the program can be successfully compiled with no error." ehh... not if you get "identifier "sigset_t" is undefined"

Comment: @SupportUkraine, the errors given by vscode can be different from the ones given by the compiler if the config file is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that `sigset_t` is only defined if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is defined.

With the C standard that gcc uses by default, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is already defined. So compiling your program with gcc doesn't produce an error.

To solve this you can add `"cStandard": "gnu11"` to you config file, or add `"defines": ["_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L"]`.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Adding "defines": ["_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L"] resolved the siginfo_t undefined issue for me. Thanks :)